# Two Ajax-Functions in 1 PHP-File

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 2 Ajax-Functions in 2 different files. One if this functions will send a data and to other one won't.

How do I need to write the PHP-If in this situation?

No-Data Ajax:

```
$.ajax("../PHP/DBConnection.php")
.done(
function(response) {                    
        var array = JSON.parse(response);});
```

I am also not quit sure if I actually send the data right in this Ajax.

```
var formData = "value= "+value;

            $.ajax("../PHP/DBConnection.php", data = formData).done(

            function(response) {
                alert(response);

            })
```

I would write the PHP-Code like this:

```
$var = $_POST['value'];
if (empty($var)) {
    echo 'there is no Data';
}
if (isset($var)) {
    echo 'there is a Data';
}
```

Edit: Ty.
I still get the following error-message back:
response = "
↵**Notice**: Undefined index: value in **C:\xampp\htdocs\IPA_Webshop\PHP\DBConnection.php** on line **64**

Line 64 is: $var = $_POST['value'];

Edit2:
I wrote this Code:

```
if (empty($_POST['value'])) {
    echo 'there is no Data';
}
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    echo 'there is a Data';
}
```

This works. But it always goes into the empty one. Even if I start the Ajay-Methoe with the Data.

Comment: `$.ajax({url: 'YOUR_URL', data: {your_data} })`

Comment: **Typo**: close your string in if(empty) condition.

Comment: Use isset to remove Undefined index error.

Comment: Be aware that if `$_POST['value'] == 0`, that you will get both responses.

Comment: Done. The Code "works" now. It goes into the PHP-Code but always into the empty($var) one. Even if I send an object with Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are your problems:

1. You aren't sending data:

`$.ajax("../PHP/DBConnection.php", data = formData).done(
-----------------------------------^`

Change it with:

`$.ajax("../PHP/DBConnection.php", data: formData).done(`

2. It's because it always enter in the `empty()` php function. With the first change you will receive the data in PHP. But is better if you write `if...else` because you can have problems returning both ifs. What about if you send empty data? The variable is set, but is empty too. I think the best approach can be this:

```
if (isset($_POST['value'] || !empty($_POST['value'])) {
    echo 'there is a Data';
} else {
    echo 'there is no Data';
}
```

With this second change, you don't have the problem that returns both values, and you avoid this error you've describe:

> Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\IPA_Webshop\PHP\DBConnection.php on line 64